# Scanf for string not working correctly

Tags: c, string

when i m running this code.Code was supposed to ask for second scanf string.But it is     printing some garbage value..Please explain this why this is happening??

```
int main()
{
    char arr[50];
    int ll;
    char sb[20];
    printf("enter the string\n");
    scanf("%[^\n]s",arr);
    printf("string=%s\n",arr);
    printf("\n enter sub");
    scanf("%[^\n]s",sb);
    printf("\n sub-string=%s",sb);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well... are you possibly entering more than 19 characters on the second input request?

Comment: @barakmanos not asking for second input..just printing some garbage value...

Comment: Second call to `scanf` - you enter input, right? Do you happen to insert more than 19 characters at this point?

Comment: @user2279196 if you check the return values from `scanf` you'll see that the second call returns `0`, indicating it hasn't written anything to `sb`

Comment: no this code not even asking for second input.

Comment: Well... then are you possibly entering more than 49 characters on the first input request?

Comment: @simonc it is not asking for second input then how to give second input..

Comment: @barakmanos  i have given less input then also not working.

Comment: @user2279196 Do you not see "enter sub" in the console?  I do, immediately followed by "sub-string=[undefined]".  This is caused by the second call to `scanf` processing the `\n` from the first string you entered, rejecting it then returning 0 to indicate that `sb` was not assigned

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tested myself...

1. `scanf("%[^\n]s",arr);` stops when it encounters `\n`
2. The `stdin` still holds `\n`
3. `scanf("%[^\n]s",sb);` stops when it encounters the very same `\n` at the end of the 1st human input

Btw it is a good practice to use the combination of `fgets` and `sscanf` instead of `scanf`.

Comment: yes i will do that..but how to improve this program without using fgets or sscanf..

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
scanf("%[^\n]s",arr);
...
scanf("%[^\n]s",sb);
```

With:

```
scanf("%49s %19s",arr,sb);
```

Comment: Your answer will give up printing `"string=%s"` on time

Comment: I think you want `scanf("%49s %19s", arr, sb);`.

Comment: @chux, thanks. I thought about this too, but was pretty that the value before 's' included the 0 character at the end of the string (did not have a working environment to try it).

Comment: It does not.  [sscanf()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf)  "The conversion specifiers s and [ always store the null terminator in addition to the matched characters. The size of the destination array must be at least one greater than the specified field width."

Comment: Thanks for the correction; answer revised... BTW, the ideal solution in this case is to build the format string `"%49s %19s"` before calling `scanf`, using something like `sprintf(format,"%%%ds %%%ds",sizeof(arr),sizeof(sb))`.

Answer (score 1):

`"%[...]"` does *not* need a trailing `'s'`.
`"%[...]"` does *not* consume leading white-space.
Whenever scanning strings, incorporate width limits.
Check `scanf()` return value.

```
char arr[50];
//         v--- Space added to consume any white-space including any \n
if (scanf(" %49[^\n]", arr) != 1) Handle_Error();
char sb[20];
if (scanf(" %19[^\n]", sb) != 1) Handle_Error();
```

In OP's original code,  OP is getting garbage because the `scanf()` did not work.  The first `"%[^\n]s"` likely worked OK, but left a `'\n'` in `stdin` for the next IO operation. The 2nd `"%[^\n]s"` tries to scan that left-over `'\n'` and since it does not match `"%[^\n]"`, `scanf()` stopped and put nothing in `sb`.  So uninitialized `sb` had whatever garbage it started with.

---

Better yet, use `fgets()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code if you do not want to use fgets or sscanf

```
int main()
{
    char arr[50];
    int ll;
    char sb[20];
    printf("enter the string\n");
    scanf("%[^\n]s",arr);
    fflush(stdin);//to clear \n from the buffer
    printf("string=%s\n",arr);
    printf("\n enter sub");
    scanf("%[^\n]s",sb);
    printf("\n sub-string=%s",sb);
    return 0;
}
```